# View only rendering when not refering to array

Tags: reactjs, native

It seems that i miss something during my first react native project:
The render function is not rendering the view when i try to display an array which is assigned to state.

i can only console log the array (in the setState callback) while also render the view when i comment out the part where i refer to the array.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  array: [],
  token: '',
}
}
setLoading = () => {
this.setState({ loading: true }, () => this.login())
}

login = async () => {
try {
  const response = await 
fetch(`http://10.0.2.2`);
  const res = await response.json();
this.setState({
      name: res.name,
      address: res.address,
      token: res.token,
    }, function () {
      this.setState({
        array: res.array,
        loading: false
      }, function () {
          //only reaching when commented out the array-part in the render 
          //function 
          console.log(this.state.array[0].grade)
      });
    })
}
catch{
  console.log('in CATCH ERROR')

} }

 render() {
if (this.state.loading) {
  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
}

return this.state.token ? (
  <View >
    <Text> {this.state.name}</Text>
     //this works !
    <Text> {this.state.array[0].prof}</Text>

      //only rendering without the mapping of the array       
    {/*this.state.array.map((item, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <Text >Grade : {item.grade}</Text>
        <Text >Class : {item.class}</Text>
        <Text >Proffessor : {item.prof}</Text>
      </div>
    ))*/}
  </View>
) : (
    <View>

      <TextInput
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
        placeholder={'Username'}

      />
      <TextInput
        value={this.state.password}
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
        placeholder={'Password'}
        secureTextEntry={true}

      />

      <Button
        title={'Login'}
        style={styles.input}
        onPress={this.login.bind(this)}
      />
    </View>

  )
};
```

according to the docs this should be possible.. any Pro here that has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: What do you expect `this.state.array` to be? I don't see that being set anywhere.

Comment: sory i had a typo there...

Comment: Why are you calling `setState` in a callback to `setState`? Is `this.state.loading` ever set to true? It looks like `loading` is never true, so you end up trying to iterate over `this.state.array` before it exists.

Comment: @ray hatfield thanks for investigating! I extended the sample to give you a batter picture. as you can see i do set the loading to true when fetching form the server. also i am able to console log the array as i show in the sample. not though when trying to render it o_0

Comment: @rayhatfield to answer the question why i setState in a callback of a setState: it was behaving similar when trying to assign the array in the first setState.. i just wanted to point out that its probably an issue with the array.. to my undestanding it doesent matter if im setState'ing in a callback of another setState. or is that wrong?

Comment: @Mesopotato no that's fine, but it doesn't seem at all necessary which is (I think) what ray was getting at. And he is right, you do not set the loading state to true at any point in your code (at least not as shown here). What are the contents of `this.state.array`? Unless it contains valid React components, it won't render anything

Comment: @robbieMilejczak thanks for taking a look. i was renaming the functions for the sample and forgot to rename the call in the setLoading function which does set the loading to true. otherwise i would not see the loadingscreen when calling the function. the problem i have is that it is not set back to false nor reaching the callback specified when refering to the array in the render function. i have jsut strings and numbers in the DB fetched. i thought those are valid react components.

Comment: @robbieMilejczak it must be something with the JS in the render function. because i can do something like this.state.array[0].prof and it renders the string correctly.

Comment: strings and numbers are valid as children, but objects are not. so if `this.state.array` was `['test string', 'test string']` it would render, but it won't render objects for you you must first map over the array as you do in your commented code.

Comment: @robbieMilejczak well i can render a specific item with this.state.array[0].{key} but not when i map over it.. what the hell am I missing?

Comment: what you're missing is that React has no idea what your objects keys are, or which ones you'd like to render. You can't render `this.state.array[0]` for example, and you couldn't render `{ prof: 'Mr. Charles', class: 'Biology', grade: 100}` because objects are not valid React children and React won't do any work to make sense of those objects to make them valid. So by referencing one the objects properties directly, you are referencing a valid React child which then renders. Does that make sense? Or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: if you [make a snack](https://snack.expo.io/) with dummy data I could better assist you

Comment: You have to use an arrow function to refer to `this`.

Comment: @robbiemilejczak that does make sense. i thought however that i am refering to a valid children when mapping and then specifying the key like i do it in the commented code. so im not shure what to change to make that work and  "uncomment" the commented code to dynamically render the arrays -.- for example: when this.state.array[0].prof is a valid child I thought that this.state.array.map((item, index) => (item.prof)) would also refer to a valid child.. where is my brain-bug here?

Comment: It's hard to say. @Sulthan raises a good point, is this the correct code? Without using an arrow function, your callback to `setState` wouldn't have access to `this.setState`, and should be causing an error

Comment: @Mesopotato the specific portion he's referring to is in your login function, when passing a callback to setState. I feel foolish as I should have spotted this immediately, but you can't use `div` in React Native you must instead use `View`. No HTML entity is valid in React Native. You can safely think of `View` as a replacement for `div`

Comment: omg. thank you guys its working in snack :) the syntax in react native is a bit seductive to use HTML tags and i thought that gets translatet like in react .. \o/